# How can I store data in memory, so that it's accessible to PHP scripts just like $_SESSION?

Tags: php

I have few scripts that must share highly dynamic data that is accessible on every HTTP request, just like $_SESSION for user's session. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: is this data different for each user, or is it the same for all users?

Comment: What's problem with `session` ?

Comment: I want to store it the way that will be accessible app-wide, only to script (all users)

Comment: If you're going to share data across requests (as I understand across different threads) - you need some external storage like Memcached.

Answer (score 6):

You may try [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).

If you are not able to use any of those, a MySQL table with memory engine might be also the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into in-memory storages, like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) ([PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)), [Redis](http://redis.io/) or MySQL's [MEMORY tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html). Also, there are a lot of other storage engines that uses RAM to store data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply store your data in a tmpfs. This link http://we-love-php.blogspot.de/2013/02/php-caching-shm-apc-memcache-mysql-file-cache.html has a nice performance comparison.